# adding include into wordpress functions.php return

Tags: php, wordpress, include

I have two scripts I need to combine for wordpress, basically my own custom share this links

The function which puts it in `the_content()`;

```
add_filter( "the_content",'addstyling', 5 );

function addstyling($content){  
    global $post;
    return ''.$content.'<br><br>Sharethis';
}
```

and the other code is just html inside a file, used through an include:

```
include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/share.php');
```

any help would be great, Im a newbie to PHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but if you want your include file adding to the post:

```
function addstyling($content){  
    global $post;
    $share = file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/share.php'); 
    return $share . $content . '<br><br>Sharethis';
}
```

Comment: Brilliantl cheers

Little change for my layout

function addstyling($content){

 global $post;
        $share = file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH . '/includes/share.php'); 
 return $content.$share;
 
}

It's including the file I want but its breaking the content when it comes to things like the URL of a href, EG:

  <li><!--Email-->
   <a href="" title="Email this article" target="_blank" id="e-share"></a>
  </li>

Works fine but below breaks
  
  <li><!--Email-->
   <a href="mailto:Body=Read this great article<url>" title="Email this article" target="_blank" id="e-share"></a>
  </li>

Any ideas?